# I'm getting segmentation fault in this code using stack

Tags: stack

This code is for deleting the middle element in the stack without using any other data structure. I'm getting segmentation fault. Help me to rectify the mistake in my code.

```
void deleteMid(stack<char>&st,int n,int temp=0)
{
    
    char x=st.top();
    st.pop();
    deleteMid(st,n,temp+1);
    
    if(temp!=n/2)
    st.push(x);
    
}
int main()
{
   stack<char> st; 
 
    st.push('1'); 
    st.push('2'); 
    st.push('3'); 
    st.push('4'); 
    st.push('5'); 
    st.push('6'); 
    st.push('7'); 
  
    deleteMid(st, st.size()); 
  
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no stopping condition in your recursion code. You have to "return" if your stack is empty or your temp variable is equal to the size of the stack.

```
if(st.empty() || temp==n)
return;
```